# Pentaho - How to set job transformation based on Kettle Property File

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

In my kettle file, I have this variable:

```
my_variable = c:/Users/me/Desktop
```

In my Pentaho job, I have a start step connected to a transformation.

In the transformation step, I am trying to run my transformation. For the location of the file, I have:

```
${my_variable}/name_of_transformation.ktr
```

For some reason, it can't find my file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you set the my_variable value in the Kettle Properties file, CLOSE OUT of Pentaho (not the file, but the entire software) and reopen it.

Do this anytime you make changes to the Kettle Properties file if you want it to be recognized.

Now, using the exact same set up as my question, it works fine. All I needed to do was close Pentaho completely and restart the software.